# How is a game I haven’t purchased on my home screen?

Tags: nintendo-switch, super-smash-bros-ultimate

My kids just got very excited by the appearance of *Super Smash Bros. Ultimate* on the home screen of the Switch, thinking I’d bought it for them while they were at school. I’m not that cool of a dad, and we don’t own the game. If I select it, it asks to insert the game cartridge so it hasn’t been purchased electronically.

It doesn’t seem very Nintendo-ey to be advertising games this way, and I’m sure I’d have heard about it if they were.

Why did this game appear and can I remove it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Nintendo Switch Online account comes with some free DLC for Super Smash Bros.

[image]

When you choose to redeem this offer (or redownload it) it puts a shortcut to the actual game on the home screen. It also downloads data that consumes 1.8 GB of storage which according to the software settings is mostly a game update but 0.2 MB is the actual DLC.

I’ve managed to remove it by going into options and deleting the software, like you would for any other software.

Comment: I somehow got splatoon 2 DLC through something, and I ended up downloading it. The game now shows on my main screen despite not owning the game so it seems like it's any DLC on the system.